# Python как вывести знак процента при форматировании строки?

Tags: python, строки, format

Например мне нужно вывести строку Запас здоровья 100%
По логике я сделаю так:

```
life_count = 100
print ("Запас здоровья: %s%" % life_count)
```

Но на деле получу ошибку

```
ValueError: incomplete format
```

Как мне вставить знак процента в эту строку без ошибки?

Comment: `print ("Запас здоровья: {}%".format(life_count))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы экранировать знак процента и python не воспринимал его как начало паттерна, нужно написать его 2 раза:

```
print("Запас здоровья: %s%%" % life_count)
```